Ubuntu 24.04 freezes during installation
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 as dual boot with Windows 10. After creating a USB stick with the Ubuntu installation media I get this screen.

I tried all options but every time got the same result
I see the loading screen with the Ubuntu logo and loading spinner, then
after a few seconds everything freezes, so I have to force shutdown my laptop.

Have you verified the ISO the boot media was made from is good? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

I also tried to install to my gf's laptop from the same USB and it work correctly. So I guess ISO is fine

I suggest you still verify it like the info in the link says.

Ok, will try it

I have an older ThinkPad t520 that is dual boot. When I try to install 24.04 it hangs as well. I have installed 24.04 with the nomodeset kernel parameter and then tried various kernels but nothing helps. IMO, the video driver in i915 is bad.

I turned off Secure boot and it worked for me
ASUSTek COMPUTER INC. T101HA
Intel Atom x5-8350 X4
4GB DDR3 1366MHZ
Intel HD Graphics (CHV)
Disk 128GB DF4128
